# Upgrading Groovy 1.7 - 2.1 Incompatability

Tags: java, groovy

I am moving from Groovy 1.76 to groovy 2.1 and am having a problem running some Java code.

I have java 7 and Groovy 2.1 all setup on my classpath. Gradle is running and my project can run all its unit tests and execute successfully just as before.

However, I have one java class that loads up one of the groovy classes and executes it (the class can be executed normally in regular gradle/groovy unit tests) and when I try to run this in the new environment it fails with the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/transform/powerassert/ValueRecorder
    at com.covestor.glossary.meta.Entity$_Rel__clinit__closure3_closure4.doCall(Entity.groovy:500)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

I have seen in other questions/discussions that some classes were removed from Groovy 1.7, so the general advice seems to be to make sure the classes are re-built against a later version of groovy - but my classes are already being built against the later version (my script that kicks off the java code actually calls `gradle clean build` first to make sure all groovy classes are properly compiled).  There are some jar dependencies as well, but none of them are built from Groovy source (all java jars).

Can anyone suggest what the problem might be? I can't see that I have any code anywhere that is still built against 1.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ValueRecorder class is used internally to implement [the power assert feature](http://hamletdarcy.blogspot.co.at/2009/05/new-power-assertions-in-groovy.html) in Groovy. Unfortunately, these classes have been moved to another package [from 1.7 to 1.8](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Intended-change-for-power-assert-in-HEAD-td380611.html).

Your error means there is still some 1.7 compiled Groovy code. That's the reason for the NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: Yep, as mentioned in the question I had seen this in several other answers but I am explicitly re-building my groovy code prior to running the code (groovy -version say 2.1, groovy_home=groovy 2.1, etc)

Comment: The version of your Groovy installation is irrelevant for a Gradle build. What matters is which version of Groovy resides on the `compile`  (or, in older Gradle versions, `groovy`) configuration of your Gradle build. `gradle dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency groovy` should provide the answer.

Comment: yes, you need to specify the correct Groovy version in your build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when upgrading, I never created a new `GROOVY_HOME` to point to the new version of groovy...did you do that and also add `$GROOVY_HOME/bin` to your path?

Comment: Yep GROOVY_HOME is set to the location of groovy 2.1, and groovy -version also says its currently 2.1