# Checking Groovy version Gradle is using

Tags: groovy, gradle

I am running gradle and have previously been running groovy 1.76.  I have now updated to groovy on my local machine (groovy_home points to groovy 2.1.2 etc).

```
$ groovy -version
Groovy Version: 2.1.2 JVM: 1.7.0_17 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux
```

However, when I am running gradle commands (gradle test, classes, etc) I believe it is not building against groovy 2.1.2 but is actually still building against 1.76.  (The reason I believe this, is that when I execute the classes I keep getting this error [Upgrading Groovy 1.7 - 2.1 Incompatability](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16424622/258813), which is related to changes made post 1.76)

Is there a way to confirm which version of groovy my gradle install is building against?

Also, can anyone confirm where I should be configuring the groovy version for gradle?

Comment: Did you update `PATH` to make sure it was correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Which Groovy library you are building against (and which Groovy compiler you are using) is determined by which Groovy library resides on the `compile` (or, in earlier Gradle versions, `groovy`) configuration. Typically a Groovy dependency is configured explicitly, but it may also be pulled in by transitive dependency management. (In case of a version conflict, the higher version wins by default. Which Groovy version(s) you have installed on your machine is irrelevant.) `gradle dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency groovy` should provide the answer.

Here is how a Groovy dependency is typically configured:

```
apply plugin: "groovy"

repositories {
    mavenCentral() // or some other repository containing a Groovy library
}

dependencies {
    // in Gradle 1.4 or earlier, replace 'compile' with 'groovy'
    compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.1.2"
}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks - was being an idiot and completely missed the groovy dependency declaration!

Answer (score 33):

While trying to check the groovy version during gradle runtime, I found you can also print the Groovy version:

```
task version { 
  doLast {
    println "Gradle version: " + project.getGradle().getGradleVersion()
    println "Groovy version: " + GroovySystem.getVersion()
  }
}
```

As examples:

```
$ ~/usr/gradle-1.8/bin/gradle -q version
Gradle version: 1.8
Groovy version: 1.8.6

$ ~/usr/gradle-2.1/bin/gradle -q version
Gradle version: 2.1
Groovy version: 2.3.6
```

Note.- `GroovySystem.getVersion()` is available since Groovy 1.6.9

Comment: I'd also add `JavaVersion.current()` in there somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

in windows you can check it using: `gradlew --v`

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-02-17 08:32:01 UTC
Revision:     61d3320259a1a0d31519bf208eb13741679a742f

Kotlin:       1.3.61
Groovy:       2.5.8
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          15.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 15.0.2+7-27)
```

on linux the command will be : `gradle --v`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using osx

```
gradle --v


------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.5.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-08-05 21:17:56 UTC
Revision:     d1daa0cbf1a0103000b71484e1dbfe096e095918

Kotlin:       1.6.21
Groovy:       3.0.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          17.0.4.1 (Homebrew 17.0.4.1+1)
OS:           Mac OS X 12.4 x86_64
```